# removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

f(z) is analytic on the punctured disc $D(0,1) - {0}$ and the real part of f is positive. Prove that f has a removable singularity at $0$.

Comment: $f$ is not entire so Liouville does not apply.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of looking at $e^{-f(z)}$, I think it's easier to do the following.

First, assume that $f$ is non-constant (otherwise the problem is trivial).

Let $\phi$ be a conformal mapping (you can write down an explict formula for $\phi$ if you want) from  the right half-space  onto the unit disc, and let $g(z) = \phi(f(z))$. Then $g$ maps the punctured disc into the unit disc, so in particular $g$ is bounded near $0$, which implies that $g$ must have a removable singularity at $z = 0$. Also, by the open mapping theorem $|g(0)| < 1$.

On the other hand,

$$f(z) = \phi^{-1}(g(z))$$

and since $|g(0)| < 1$ and, and $\phi$ is continuous on the unit disc, the limit $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z) = \phi^{-1}(g(0))$ also exists, which means that $0$ is a removable singularity for $f$.

Comment: I can not understand the use of open mapping theorem. Also how the limit become $\phi^{-1}(g(0))$.? Would you kindly explain for me sir?